# How to restrict access to custom forms

Tags: display-form

I have created a custom disp-form and custom edit-form in a customized sharepoint list. I'd like to restrict access to those 2 custom forms to a specific security group.

Can someone advise how I can add some sort of permission to these forms?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best example I've found for this http://www.estruyf.be/blog/sharepoint-2007-create-permissions-on-list-views/

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I've managed to do that, however it has just secured the list view. I'm not sure how i can then limit access to the two forms dispform and editform. If i add them to the CustomActions list, the appear in both the new secured view and the original views in the ECB menu. And everyone who can access either lists can access the forms.

Answer (score -1):

Create a simple webpart which checks for access permissions. Add these webpart into the forms.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. Are you able to provide some more detail on how to do this?

Comment: In your custom webpart, you can check the access permission for the currently logged in user. Get the security group to which the user belongs to and if that doesnt match with the exepected group, then redirect the user to an "Access denied" page.